# Show that ${ \mu(A \times B)=\mu_1(A) \cdot \mu_2(B) }$

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

I need help with a task.
 Let ${ X_1 }$${ X_2 }$ sets and ${\mathscr{A_i} \subset \mathcal{P}(X_i)}$ two algebras on ${X_i}$ for i=1,2. Let also ${ \mu_i: \mathscr{A_i} \to [0, \infty ] }$ be 2 contents on  ${X_i}$ and ${  \mathscr{A}=\mathscr{A_1}\times\mathscr{A_2}=\{C \subset X \vert \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}{A_i} \times {B_i}}$ with  ${{A_i} \in \mathscr{A_1},{B_i} \in \mathscr{A_2}}$ and ${ n \in \mathbb{N}\} }$. Prove that there is exactly one content ${ \mu:\mathscr{A} \to [0, \infty ] }$ which holds that
$${ \mu(A \times B)=\mu_1(A) \cdot \mu_2(B)  }$$ 
for every ${{A_i} \in \mathscr{A_1}}$ and ${{B_i} \in \mathscr{A_2}}$. 
In another thread someone suggested the monotone class theorem but I am not sure whether I can use it here (and I'm pretty sure it is not in my script anyway) and I tried to show it by using  half-open intervals(Cuboid, not sure what you call it in english) but that got way to tedious and complicated.

Comment: What does the notation "${ \mu:(A \times B)=\mu_1(A)\mu_2(B)  }$" mean?

Comment: My bad, I just corrected it.

Comment: Use induction on n to show that you can decompose everything in $\mathscr{A}$ into disjoint rectangles, and then, using additivity and the defined value of the measure of the rectangles, there can be only one value of the content on $\mathscr{A}$.